# Я не для того выходила за него замуж, чтобы его носки стирать

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, эти два предложения различные или их можно считать целевыми? (Во втором предложении, если я понимаю правильно, негативная цель указывается.)

> (1) Я не для того выходила за него замуж, чтобы его носки стирать.
>
> (2) Я выходила за него замуж, не для того чтобы его носки стирать.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Оба предложения целевые, но во втором целевой союз "не для того чтобы" расчленяется, так как перед ним стоит отрицательная частица:

Я выходила за него замуж не для того, чтобы его носки стирать.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ дополнен и исправлен.

Эти предложения  со сходным содержанием имеют разную структуру и разное **грамматическое** значение.

1) Я выходила за него замуж **не для того,  чтобы** его носки стирать.  2) Я **не для того** выходила за него замуж, **чтобы** его носки стирать.

Формально во втором предложении местоименная часть союза перенесена в середину предложения, но надо разобраться, что это меняет с точки зрения смысла.

Это особый тип предложений (в грамматике их называют несвободные/фразеологизованные конструкции  со значением  обусловленности). Они интересны тем, что при наличии союза ЧТОБЫ **значение цели может ослабляться или совсем исчезать.**

**В первом предложении** (классическая форма) отрицается значение цели, но при этом мы должны сделать вывод, что замужество в общем случае имеет вполне конкретную цель. **Во втором предложении** примерно такое же содержание, но выражено оно по-другому: **не такова причина моего замужества, чтобы оно имело такое следствие**. Таким образом, от прямого целевого значения мы переходим к значению причинно-следственному.

**Для справок** (общая характеристика)

В  предложениях подобной структуры рассматривается **необходимое, достаточное иди недостаточное основание**  для предполагаемого (ирреального)  **следствия (отсюда целевой союз ЧТОБЫ).** Также в  главном предложении может выражаться **отсутствие  основания для возможного следствия**, высказанного в придаточной части.

**Другие примеры с союзом ЧТОБЫ** (с ослабленным ли отсутствующим значением цели): Я **не миллионер, чтобы** оплачивать такие счета. **Нужно** быть очень наивным, **чтобы** верить ему. Это место **недостаточно удобное, чтобы** устроить привал. **Достаточно небольшого сквозняка, чтобы** он простудился.

Comment: Что-то Вы здесь намудрили.Отрицание не, стоящее перед указательным словом для того, отрицает цель действия, т.е. придаточное предложение, в обоих случаях.Здесь  главное предложение обусловливает  придаточное,а при   взаимной обусловленности нельзя выделить главную и придаточную части. Неужели здесь можно перепутать: носки стирать, чтобы выйти замуж или выйти замуж, чтобы стирать носки? Разная структура лишь расставляет разные акценты: в первом отрицается  цель замужества, во втором ставится под сомнение само замужество

Comment: Материал взят из книги "Синтаксис современного р. я.", 2013 год, курс лекций для педвузов (от себя я ничего не добавляю). В школьной практике, возможно, все предложения с союзом ЧТОБЫ следует относить к придаточным цели. Но  синтаксис русского языка более сложен, в нем, кроме классических моделей, есть другие формы.  Мне кажется, что в данном случае сравниваются  два таких варианта. Содержание одно и то же, но несвободная модель с предполагаемым следствием здесь больше подходит. Ведь о стирке носков как о цели замужества говорится не в прямом смысле, поэтому значение цели ослаблено.

Comment: Вы что, всерьёз считаете, что здесь придаточное следствия? Очень интересно...Я не знаю, что написано в учебнике для педвузов, но Вы явно что-то не так поняли.Сл. предложение, у которого части обусловлены не односторонне (когда придаточная зависит от главной), а взаимно, называется сложноподчинённым предложением с взаимообусловленными частями. В таком предложении нельзя выделить главную и придаточную части. Это временные(Еще солнце не дошло до половины неба, как все запорожцы собрались в круг. ); сравнительно-сопоставительные  (Чем ночь темней, тем ярче звезды)

Comment: Или,может быть, речь о следующем: Разница в грамматике и стилевой семантике. Если мы расчленяем составной союз ДЛЯ ТОГО ЧТОБЫ, то связь предложений взаимообусловленная. Если используем простой союз ЧТОБЫ, то имеем чисто подчинительную связь придаточного предложения по отношению к главному (главное предложение не зависит от придаточного и может обойтись без него). Речь не о типах придаточных, а о том, что иногда предложения тесно связаны, а иногда главные употребляются самостоятельно, без придаточных.

Comment: В данном случае речь идет не о расчленении союза, а о перенесении местоименной части союза в середину предложения, а это более серьезная перестройка структуры предложения.  Приведу цитату (может быть, Вы ее иначе поймете). "Если в главной части содержится отрицание, то предложение выражает отсутствие необходимого основания для реализации ситуации придаточного, которая оформлена как ирреальное (отвергаемое) следствие (союз ЧТОБЫ): Я же не врач, чтобы давать советы". Мне кажется, что значение цели здесь явно отсутствует.